# secure uploader file by php

Tags: php, upload

I have an uploader in my website and when I use this code to check file type

```
if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/gif' || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/png' )
 {
     $file_Name = time().".".end(explode(".",$_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"]));
     $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] = $file_Name;
       move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . @$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$msg .='Your file was uploaded successfully';
}
```

but some hacker they can hacked and upload php file , is there any way more security

Note: when I create php file and I change its extinction to .jpg then I upload the file it will be uploaded

Comment: Never put user-uploaded documents in your site's doc root.  Never let the user specify the file name.  Never trust the content type, or anything else sent from the user.  If you do those 3 things, you're covered.

Comment: Essentially @Brad is right, never trust a user when it comes to uploading client side files. At Least you are filtering server side, I have seen some smug developers that rely on client side filetype validation and think it is going to stop people doing something malicious when in fact anyone that knows how to use Chrome's Inspect element can completely bypass it.

Comment: Making the permissions of the file uploaded as read-only should help too.  The user will never execute a file on your machine.

Comment: In addition to what Brad said, I usually set-up a dummy temp folder where I move the file with a unique ID attached to the current user (nonce) and then when they submit the form you verify that the nonce matches and move the file into the final location. Finally you set-up a cron job to delete files in temp every 24-48h.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's utterly vulnerable. In `$_FILES`, the following parameters are under **USER** control:

```
['type']
['name']
```

it is beyond trivial to forge an upload, allowing such things as:

```
['type'] = 'image/jpeg';
['name'] = 'nasty_hacking_script.php';
```

and boom, they're through your (laughable) security. Since you're allowing the user-defined file extension to get through your system, and only doing a trivial time-based renaming, you'll end up with something like

```
 1234567890.php
```

in your site's document root. Given the name is time-based, it's also trivial for the attacker to simply poke at your server and guess what the exact time-of-upload was, e.g.

```
 for($i = 1234567800; $i <= 124000000; $i++) {
     see_if_url_exists("$i.php");
 }
```

until they find their script. Now they have **TOTAL** control of your site, and most likely the server as well.

In short, your code provides about as much security as a piece of wet toilet paper. It is BEYOND dangerous.

Comment: dear Marc B  how they can uplaod .php file while the code check the file type if this code : 
if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/gif' || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']=='image/png' )
 {

Comment: please give me a solution if you can

Comment: Did you read my answer? `['type']` is under USER control, meaning they can FORGE any mime-type they want to. You need to use server-side mime-type determination, e.g. [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo)